U-Boot 2023.04 fixed-link property on custom board based on beaglebone black
I'm looking for a solution enable my custom board to load the kernel or at least the image from the network in u-boot. The setup is an AM2258 processor attached to an KSZ8863MLL via GMII1-port (SoC) and Port3 on the switch.
At first I was stuggling to get the setup running in Linux (6.1). As I've configured fixed-link in the device-tree it was working fine. So I would assume the electrical interface is ok.
Following the documentation of u-boot I've included the fixed-link property in:
&cpsw_emac0 {
   phy_id = \<&davinci_mdio\>, \<0\>;
   phy-mode = "mii";
   fixed-link {
       speed = <100>;
       full-duplex;
   };
};

And enabled the fixed-link driver in the u-boot menuconfig.
But at start u-boot is only complaining about missing phy at address 0.
Yesterday I was curious as the document for the fixed-link in u-boot is stating it has to be in the ethernet-node. So I've moved it to &mac.
&mac {
   pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
   pinctrl-0 = <&cpsw_default>;
   pinctrl-1 = <&cpsw_sleep>;

   fixed-link {
       speed = <100>;
       full-duplex;
   };
};

Now it has got even stranger as I'm getting:
U-Boot SPL 2023.04-ti-g836606420854 (May 09 2024 - 05:42:45 +0000)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2023.04-ti-g836606420854 (May 09 2024 - 05:42:45 +0000)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
Core:  160 devices, 18 uclasses, devicetree: separate
WDT:   Started wdt@44e35000 with servicing every 1000ms (60s timeout)
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   ERROR: no/invalid <fixed-link> property!
eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0

The parser seems unable to read my fixed-link property and tries to fetch it in the old-style. This I've tested too and it fails with the same message.
Can anyone help me out with this?
Regards,
Sombohan
